# How to generate "pretty" output from the str() function in R

Tags: r, formatting

I have a moderate-sized data set that is 1000 rows by 81 columns. I'd like to use the output from `str()`, but I'd like to present it in a "prettier" way. I've tried things like this:

```
df %>% str() %>% kableExtra::kbl() %>% kableExtra::kable_minimal()
```

and

```
tbl_summary(as.data.frame(str(df)))
```

but neither works. I'm not married to `str()` or to any specific package, but that's the kind of summary I'm going for.

In the end, this is intended to generate an HTML file, but I'd like it to work with PDF output as well.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: This is pretty vague... maybe you want to take a look at `qwraps2` package? It seems to offer nicely customizable summaries [as seen in this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qwraps2/vignettes/summary-statistics.html)? Or `psych::describe`? These are some of the first things that came up when I searched for "r data frame summary pretty table".

Comment: It's unfortunately vague; apologies. I'm not looking for anything more descriptive than `str()` if I can help it. The `psych::describe()` function is great but isn't what I need for this part of my analysis. I'm really looking for something I could pipe the `str()` output into to get a prettier output.

Comment: Well, `str` prints its output, but doesn't actually return anything, so it is not pipe-friendly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update II:**
[image]
This can be achieved making use of this gist `devtools::source_gist('4a0a5ab9fe7e1cf3be0e')`

```
<devtools::source_gist('4a0a5ab9fe7e1cf3be0e')>

  print(strtable(iris, factor.values=as.integer), na.print='') %>% 
    kable() %>% 
    htmlTable()
```

**Update I:**
you could extend:

```
data.frame(variable = names(iris),
           class = sapply(iris, typeof),
           levels = sapply(iris, class),
           first_values = sapply(iris, function(x) paste0(head(x),  collapse = ", ")),
           levels_values = sapply(iris, function(x) paste0(unique(x), collapse =", ")),
           row.names = NULL) %>% 
  kable() %>% 
  htmlTable()
```

[image]

**First answer:**
Something like this using `iris` dataset:

```
library(knitr)
library(magrittr)
library(htmlTable)

data.frame(variable = names(iris),
           classe = sapply(iris, typeof),
           first_values = sapply(iris, function(x) paste0(head(x),  collapse = ", ")),
           row.names = NULL) %>% 
  kable() %>% 
  htmlTable()
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful. I tried adding a column for levels (factor variables) and NA values (numeric), but couldn't get it. Thoughts?

Comment: I have updated with a new version. Using`is.na` or `complete.cases` did not work for NA values. I am trying another way. I will update as soon as possible.

Comment: Error: GitHub PAT must have one of these forms:
  * 40 hexadecimal digits (older PATs)
  * A 'ghp_' prefix followed by 36 to 251 more characters (newer PATs)

Comment: See here <https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/06/str-implementation-for-data-frames/>

Answer (score 3):

`skimr` and `gt` (or kable, or flextable, or DT, or many other table packages) could also work here:

```
mtcars |>
  skimr::skim() |>
  gt::gt()
```

[image]